# Array_slice() doesn't work as expected on nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

So, I was designing a function that can take multiple arguments via the spread operator (`...$arg`)

but it can also take a simple input array.
I want to access the first element of the `array` with the `array_slice()` method, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
    // This is what the spread argument passes into the function if it gets a single array
    $arg = [
      ['value1', 'value2', 'valueN'],  
    ];

    // Accessing first element via array_slice:
    var_export( array_slice($arg, 0, 1) );
```

Expected result:

```
     array (
       0 => 'value1',
       1 => 'value2',
       2 => 'valueN',
     )
```

The result is basically equal to the input array:

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => 'value1',
        1 => 'value2',
        2 => 'valueN',
      ),
    )
```

I know I can just simply access the `0th` element (`$arg[0]`) to get the first item, but I'm curious why `array_slice()` doesn't work as I would expect. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as expected. It's returning the first element of your `$arg` array, which is the array with the key 0 containing an array by itself and not the contents of the first element. You're just misunderstanding how array_slice actually works.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'value1',
    1 => 'value2',
    2 => 'valueN',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Ah, I get it now, it _always_ returns an array. I don't know what I was thinking... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting the first value from your array. array_slice return the sliced array. You can use array_shift instead which will shifts the first value of the array off and returns it.

```
print_r(array_shift($arg));
```

Output:

```
array (
       0 => 'value1',
       1 => 'value2',
       2 => 'valueN',
     )
```

Comment: Thanks! Using `current($arg)` also does the job.